# How can get First character of string of any html tag and bind to other tag in php?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I achieve the below scenario with php?

#### Case 1

```
Input : <h2>Test text <img src="./test.png" /></h2>
Output : <span>T</span><h2>est text <img src="./test.png" /></h2>
```

#### Case 2

```
Input : <p>Test text</h2>
Output : <span>T</span><p>est text</p>
```

#### Case 3

```
Input - <h2><img src="./test.png" /> Test text </h2>
Output - <span>T</span><h2><img src="./test.png" /> est text</h2>
```

In the input html may be there are so many tags will included. I want any of first block holding the html

#### I have tried below code

```
<?php
$firstLetter = strip_tags(get_sub_field('text'));
$firstLetter = $firstLetter[0];
?>
<div class="capLetter"><?php echo $firstLetter; ?></div>
<?php echo substr(get_sub_field('text'), 4); ?>
```

Comment: Asking for people to write full code or algorithms isn't a great fit for this website. Also a lot of details are missing; how do you read in the HTML, what did you try already, are you using a HTML parser, how are you running the PHP etc.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @JoelPeltonen I have updated Question with code snippet I have tried

Comment: Nice! Hmm, so this looks like wordpress/ACF code. I think you won't be able to use strip_tags because that loses the elements, which you need to keep. I would look into finding a PHP HTML parser. Sadly I have never used one. This would be Muuuuch much easier in the browser using javascript though, would that be an option for you?

Comment: Right getting the `.text()` inside element would more easier than doing with php snippet. Thanks @JoelPeltonen I try with JS once.

Comment: How is the given problem related to Wordpress? You haven't shared any such code

Comment: `<span>T</span><h2>est text` would be pretty big nonsense to begin with. Any tool that tries to parse your page structure, would now determine that the H2 headline was saying "est text". If people using screenreaders let the ToC automatically created from the document's headline, get read to them, it would also read out "est text". And in that ToC context, the `T` from the preceding span would not even be there ... If anything, this should be made into `<h2><span>T</span>est text`

Comment: But what is the _purpose_ behind this anyway? If you want to _style_ the first letter differently - the [::first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) pseudo class in CSS exists.

Comment: @CBroe I want that character in different HTML element for setting style of positioning it out of the current div. And I have just provided example in here with `span` tag. That doesn't mean you need to say nonsense to any questions.

Comment: ::first-letter css only support font related things https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-letter/ 

Thanks @CBroe for guiding me alot

Comment: @NicoHaase `get_sub_field` is a function in ACF, which is a wordpress plugin. I was thinking that that was some kind of HTML parser, so if `get_sub_field` would return an HTML tree, this would have been quite different to handle :) That's all that I meant with the WP comment. I have also done PHP script that does in-server HTML-to-PDF (Generating invoices, where things like screen readers are irrelevant) which again would make this different to handle.

Comment: _"That doesn't mean you need to say nonsense to any questions"_ - I did not say nonsense to your question in general, but to the specific structure your examples suggested you intended on using. Doing this would actively be causing problems for people who use assistive technologies, like the ones I mentioned. And if you call yourself proficient in HTML, you should've rather been aware of that already, before someone needs to point it out.

Comment: @CBroe thanks to point it out. I would be thankful to you if you can have a look on the answer. Will it sufficient code or any loop hole in that broke at any of the case. Can you check once with your expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous answer gets the issue if the first element comes the `<img />` tag then it will not works. So I tried to hide the first char with css.

#### Try below code

```js
var mystring = document.querySelectorAll(".mystring");
var letter = document.querySelectorAll(".letter");

for (var i = 0; i < mystring.length; i++) {
    const nameletter = mystring[i].textContent.trim();
    letter[i].innerHTML = nameletter.charAt(0);
}
```

```css
.mystring::first-letter,
.mystring ::first-letter {
    font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstLetterCaps">
    <h1 class="letter"></h1>
    <div class="mystring"><img src="./test.png" />
        <h2>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then
            start writing</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="firstLetterCaps">
    <h1 class="letter"></h1>
    <div class="mystring">This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</div>
</div>
<div class="firstLetterCaps">
    <h1 class="letter"></h1>
    <div class="mystring">Great <em>communications</em>, great <em>design</em> and great <em>results</em> starts with
        <em>well considered thinking</em>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After dogged so many possibilities I created one function with **jQuery**

#### Try below code

```js
$(".firstLetterCaps").each(function () {
    let firstChar = $(this).text().trim();
    let stringElement = $(this).find("*").eq(1);
    let stringElementText = stringElement.html().slice(1);

    stringElement.html(stringElementText);
    $(this).children(".capLetter").html(firstChar.charAt(0));
});
```

```css
.firstLetterCaps{
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="firstLetterCaps">
    <div class="capLetter"></div>
    <h2>Test text <img src="./test.png" /></h2>
</div>
<div class="firstLetterCaps">
    <div class="capLetter"></div>
    <p>Great <em>communications</em>, great <em>design</em> and great <em>results</em> starts with <em>well considered thinking</em></p>
</div>
<div class="firstLetterCaps">
    <div class="capLetter"></div>
    <h2>Demo text </h2><h2>Test text</h2>
</div>
```